# Dynamically name x-node of networkD3 sankey

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am trying to have produce a shiny application in which a Sankey plot, produced using NetworkD3, dynamically produces x-node labels. I think this requires passing a reactive element to `onRender`, but I am not sure how to do this.

I see an answer here: [How to add columnn titles in a Sankey chart networkD3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66813278/how-to-add-columnn-titles-in-a-sankey-chart-networkd3), but this solves the dynamic naming by calling `.text("Step " + (i + 1));` in the `onRender` function. My labels are not so generic that I can just iterate and paste (the example below uses simplified names).

Here is an example:

```
library('shiny') 
library('tidyverse')
library('networkD3')
library(shinyWidgets)
library(htmlwidgets)

#Create the data
df <- data.frame('A' = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'), 
                 'B' = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '3'), 
                 'C' = c('red', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green'))

#Create the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Sidebar to select x-nodes
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(inputId = 'var_select', 
                  label = 'Variables', 
                  choices = colnames(df), 
                  selected = colnames(df), 
                  multiple = TRUE, 
                  pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE))
    ), 
   #Mainpanel to show sankey plot
    mainPanel(
     sankeyNetworkOutput('plot',
                         height = '800px')
   ) 
  )
)

#Create the server
server <- function(input, session, output) {
  #create a reactive function that outputs the selected variables
  df_sankey <- reactive({
    df %>%
      select(input$var_select) 
  })
  
  #Prepare for plotting in NetworkD3
  links1 <- reactive({
    df_sankey() %>%
      mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  # add a row id
      pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "col", values_to = "source") %>%  # gather all columns
      mutate(col = match(col, names(df_sankey()))) %>%  # convert col names to col ids
      mutate(source = paste0(source, '_', col)) %>%  # add col id to node names
      group_by(row) %>%
      mutate(target = lead(source, order_by = col)) %>%  # get target from following node in row
      ungroup() %>%
      filter(!is.na(target)) %>%  # remove links from last column in original data
      group_by(source, target) %>%
      summarise(value = n(), .groups = "drop")  # aggregate and count similar links
  })
  
  #Now create the nodes
  nodes <- reactive({
    data.frame(id = unique(c(links1()$source, links1()$target)),
               stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
      mutate(name = sub('_[0-9]*$', '', id))
  })
  
  #Mutate a soutrce id variable - have to create this as links2 to prevent endless recursion
  links2 <- reactive({
    mutate(links1(), source_id = match(links1()$source, nodes()$id) - 1)
  })
  
  #Do the same for target id
  links <- reactive({
    mutate(links2(), target_id = match(links2()$target, nodes()$id) - 1) %>%
      data.frame()
  })
  
  
  #Build the sankey plot
  plot1 <- reactive({
    sankeyNetwork(Links = links(), Nodes = nodes(),
                  Source = 'source_id', Target = 'target_id', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
                  fontSize = 14)
  })
  
  #Here is the problematic code
  #under code starting var labels - i need that to be produced by a reactive element: colnames(df_sankey())
  #Without this it just take the number of var labels as there are selected variables
  output$plot <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    onRender(plot1(), '
      function(el) { 
        var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes().map(d => d.x).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
        var labels = ["A", "B", "C"]; 
        cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
          d3.select(el).select("svg")
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", d)
            .attr("y", 12)
            .text(labels[i]);
        })
      }
    ')
  })
  
}

#call the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I call out the problem in the comments above the `onRender` function. Effectively I need var labels to take a reactive function generated by something like: `colnames(df_sankey())`. If i put that code in for var labels (which i appreciate is a wild guess), it just fails. Without the reactive function the code just loops through the `var labels` according to the number of variables selected. You can see the problem if you select var A and C - C gets labelled B. I also tried (another guess):

```
  output$plot <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    onRender(plot1(), '
      function(el, node_labels) { 
        var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes().map(d => d.x).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
        var labels = [node_labels]; 
        cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
          d3.select(el).select("svg")
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", d)
            .attr("y", 12)
            .text(labels[i]);
        })
      }
    ', node_labels = colnames(df_sankey()))
```

But that also fails. I can't seem to find an explanation for how to pass reactive functions to `onRender`.

How can I pass a reactive function to the `onRender` function so that i can dynamically name my x-nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsCode` argument of `htmlwidgets::onRender()` is simply a character vector that happens to contain valid JavaScript code, so you can build/modify that just as you can any other string in R. If you want to set the array values of the `var labels = ["A", "B", "C"];` line of the JavaScript dynamically, you could do something like this...

```r
col_labels <- c("A", "B", "C")
col_lables_js_arrray_string <- paste0('["', paste(col_labels, collapse = '", "'), '"]')

render_js <- paste('
function(el) { 
  var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes()
    .map(d => d.x)
    .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
    .sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
  var labels = ', col_lables_js_arrray_string, ';
  cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
    d3.select(el).select("svg")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", d)
    .attr("y", 12)
    .text(labels[i]);
  })
}
')

htmlwidgets::onRender(x = p, jsCode = render_js)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this and for the edit. I hadn't appreciated that I could just use paste to amend the string that runs as js code. I will post the complete working code for this below. An enormous help as always.

Answer (score 0):

Full working code for the above example posted below:

```
library('shiny') 
library('tidyverse')
library('networkD3')
library('shinyWidgets')
library('htmlwidgets')

#Create the data
df <- data.frame('A' = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'), 
                 'B' = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '3'), 
                 'C' = c('red', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green'))

#Create the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Sidebar to select x-nodes
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(inputId = 'var_select', 
                  label = 'Variables', 
                  choices = colnames(df), 
                  selected = colnames(df), 
                  multiple = TRUE, 
                  pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE))
    ), 
   #Mainpanel to show sankey plot
    mainPanel(
     sankeyNetworkOutput('plot',
                         height = '800px')
   ) 
  )
)

#Create the server
server <- function(input, session, output) {
  #create a reactive function that outputs the selected variables
  df_sankey <- reactive({
    df %>%
      select(input$var_select) 
  })
  #create a reactive function for the array that will populate the var labels
  col_lables_js_arrray_string <- reactive({
    paste0('["', paste(colnames(df_sankey()), collapse = '", "'), '"]')
  })
  
  #Prepare for plotting in NetworkD3
  links1 <- reactive({
    df_sankey() %>%
      mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  # add a row id
      pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "col", values_to = "source") %>%  # gather all columns
      mutate(col = match(col, names(df_sankey()))) %>%  # convert col names to col ids
      mutate(source = paste0(source, '_', col)) %>%  # add col id to node names
      group_by(row) %>%
      mutate(target = lead(source, order_by = col)) %>%  # get target from following node in row
      ungroup() %>%
      filter(!is.na(target)) %>%  # remove links from last column in original data
      group_by(source, target) %>%
      summarise(value = n(), .groups = "drop")  # aggregate and count similar links
  })
  
  #Now create the nodes
  nodes <- reactive({
    data.frame(id = unique(c(links1()$source, links1()$target)),
               stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
      mutate(name = sub('_[0-9]*$', '', id))
  })
  
  #Mutate a soutrce id variable - have to create this as links2 to prevent endless recursion
  links2 <- reactive({
    mutate(links1(), source_id = match(links1()$source, nodes()$id) - 1)
  })
  
  #Do the same for target id
  links <- reactive({
    mutate(links2(), target_id = match(links2()$target, nodes()$id) - 1) %>%
      data.frame()
  })
  
  
  #Build the sankey plot
  plot1 <- reactive({
    sankeyNetwork(Links = links(), Nodes = nodes(),
                  Source = 'source_id', Target = 'target_id', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
                  fontSize = 14)
  })
  #paste the array for the var labels into the string that will run as valid js code
  render_js <- reactive({
    paste('function(el) {
        var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes().map(d => d.x).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
        var labels = ',col_lables_js_arrray_string(),';
        cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
          d3.select(el).select("svg")
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", d)
            .attr("y", 12)
            .text(labels[i]);
        })
      }')
  })
  
  #render the sankey network, by calling the reactive js code string
  output$plot <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    onRender(plot1(), jsCode = render_js())
  })

}

#call the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```