# How to print a htmlwidgets::onRender() title added to a Sankey diagram Network D3 in rmarkdown pdf

Tags: r-markdown, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3, onrender

I have crated this Sankey diagram based on the networkD3::sankeyNetwork() package. I have added the column names based on this post [How to add columnn titles in a Sankey chart networkD3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66813278/how-to-add-columnn-titles-in-a-sankey-chart-networkd3) . However, when I knit it into a pdf file, it does not capture the added column names. I have been looking around to find a solution but have not been successful. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

````r
---
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

links <- data.frame(
  source=c("group_A","group_A", "group_B", "group_C", "group_C", "group_E"), 
  target=c("group_C","group_D", "group_E", "group_F", "group_G", "group_H"), 
  value=c(2,3, 2, 3, 1, 3)
)

nodes <- data.frame(
  name = unique(c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)))
)

links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                   Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                   Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
                   sinksRight=FALSE)

htmlwidgets::onRender(p, '
  function(el) { 
    var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes().map(d => d.x).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
      d3.select(el).select("svg")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", d)
        .attr("y", 12)
        .text("Step " + (i + 1));
    })
  }
')
```
````

[image]